# String is not assigned to another string in correct format in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

Following is the code is used

```
Dim FilterExpression As string
Dim oDate as DateTime

oDate=System.DateTime.Now
 FilterExpression = " quot_date >= '" + oDate.ToString() + "'"
```

Before Assign oDate contains `#2/10/2013 6:10:35 PM#` this but when it assign to FilterExpression it becomes `quot_date >= '10/02/2013 6:10:35 PM'`
Date is changing his format

Any idea why?

Comment: This isn't `C#`, this is `VB.Net`.

Comment: Yes, but I like to help, so use the correct ToString() overload which takes a format specifier. :)

Comment: This is VB.NET, not C#, but that aside, have you tried the overloads for the `.ToString()` method with the exact `DateTime` format you wish to produce? E.g. `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, that's VB rather than C#.

Secondly, the value of `oDate` is a value of type `DateTime`. Whereas `#2/10/2013 6:10:35 PM` is a VB *literal* of type `DateTime`, that's not representation used by `DateTime.ToString`. It's using the default format for the current culture - which is apparently one using `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`, effectively.

If you need a specific string representation, you can use a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) string format as an argument to `DateTime.ToString`, and you can also specify the culture to use. (For example, with a custom string format you may well want to use the invariant culture.)

However, if you're trying to use this as a *value* - for example in a SQL query - it would be better not to need to convert it into a string to start with. You haven't told us much about what you're trying to achieve, but I would *try* to avoid converting it into a string unless you really have to.